# Can I share persistent volumes between builds in Google Cloud Build?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-build

My build process is somewhat slow and it would be very handy if I could speed it up by reusing some assets from previous builds.

I've found that one can define [volumes](https://cloud.google.com/cloud-build/docs/build-config#volumes) to share volumes between steps but is it possible to share folders between **builds**?

Comment: Loading and saving assets between Cloud Build runs is something you would need to do manually. Cloud Build does not have storage persistence between builds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it's layer of your container, you can use [Kaniko cache feature](https://cloud.google.com/cloud-build/docs/kaniko-cache). Else, you need to export the content somewhere (on Cloud Storage, it's a great place for this) and then import it on the next Build.

Tips: You can create [custom builder](https://cloud.google.com/cloud-build/docs/cloud-builders#writing_your_own_custom_builder). Define yours which saves the assets, and another one which retrieves the assets. Like this, add them simple at the end and the beginning of your pipeline to achieve this easily and in a more reusable manner.

Comment: We have a pretty big rails application and the slowest part in the build process is compiling assets (takes about an hour) which can be significantly sped up by using cache. I've seen Kaniko cache but I don't think it can help. Storing and retrieving archived cache folder on Cloud Storage seems feasible. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if that helps in your case, but did you consider saving objects in the google cloud storage buckets?